# Firefox does not save file with extension

Tags: python, django

I have a view in my Django application which creates a XLSX file and returns it to the user for download:

```
# Creates the response
response = HttpResponse(output.read(),
                            content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}".xlsx'.format(tournament.name)
```

When I try to download the file in Chrome, it works perfectly: the file is downloaded with filename "blabla.xlsx".

However with Firefox, it is downloaded with filename "blabla" (no extension).

Did you ever encounter this problem?

Comment: try to replace `'attachment; filename="{}".xlsx` --> `'attachment; filename="{}.xlsx"`

Comment: Thank you, it corrected the problem.